# Unable to upload a system file using AutoIt in Selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, autoit

I'm trying to upload a system file. To do this I use AutoIt, the following code is the script that I wrote to upload the file (an AutoIt script):

```
Opt("MustDeclareVars", 1) ;0=no, 1=require pre-declare

Main()

Func Main()
    Local Const $dialogTitle = $CmdLine[2]
    Local Const $timeout = 5

    Local $windowFound = WinWait($dialogTitle, "", $timeout)

    $windowFound = WinWait($dialogTitle, "", $timeout)
    Local $windowHandle

    If $windowFound Then
        $windowHandle = WinGetHandle("[LAST]")
        WinActivate($windowHandle)

        ControlSetText($windowHandle, "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", $CmdLine[1])
        ControlClick($windowHandle, "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:&Open]")        
    Else
        MsgBox(0, "", "Could not find window.")
        Exit 1
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

After this I compiled the script, the below script that I wrote to execute the `.exe` file created is:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\selenium\\auto.exe",
                      "C:\\Users\\selenium\\test.png", "Open").start();
```

There is a choose file button in my application, my test case is working untill clicking that button, after opening the system window. Then I'm not able to open the file with the directory specified above.

**I'm using Selenium Web Driver Version -- 2.33 with FireFox version 21 and AutoIT version 2.28**

Comment: Have you tried to directly type in to the file upload text field?

Comment: Yes Amey, but it it not working...

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working, do you get a Selenium Error?  If yes whats the error?

Comment: I'm not getting any selenium error, the program is ending with no errors.. Amey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Open" argument refers to the window title, which is different from browser to browser.
Chrome -"Open"
Firefox - "File Upload"
IE - "Choose File to Upload"

So, in your case, instead of this line -

`Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\selenium\\auto.exe",
                      "C:\\Users\\selenium\\test.png", "Open").start();`

You need to use:

```
 Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\selenium\\auto.exe",
                      "C:\\Users\\selenium\\test.png", "File Upload").start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using AutoIt to handle a file upload.. simply use `IWebElement.SendKeys` on the file input element, and the file upload dialog will be handled automatically for you.

So, instead of clicking on the file browser button...

Find the input element on the page where `<input type="file"/>`, and then create then create the appropriate locator to retrieve the element.

Then, use `IWebElement.SendKeys()` to this element with the full path of the file you want to upload.